# Python file path in Windows

Tags: python, windows

I am using Windows 10.
I have this code,

```
script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
temp = cs(os.path.join(script_dir+"first.txt"), 
    os.path.join(script_dir+"second.text"), 
    os.path.join(script_dir+"third.txt"))
```

It executes in git bash, but it throws an error in powershell and cmd.
How can I fix this code, so that I can execute this code in anywhere?

============================================================
Edit:
it says, it cannot find `.first.txt` and following files.
It also throws this error,
`DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`

============================================================
Edit2:
`cs` is a class I created.

```
class cs:
    info = {}
    result = {}
    def __init__(self, first, second, third, output=None):
        self.output = ""
        self.first = first
        self.second = second
        self.third = third
    def decrypt(self):
        pass
```

I don't know why it works in git bash, but not in powershell and cmd

Comment: what error does it throw?

Comment: what is that `cs` function you are using? This doesn't give enough information. Please add all relevant code and the error message you are getting.

Comment: @MarcusWeinberger I added.

Answer (score 1):

The correct code is

```
script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
temp = cs(os.path.join(script_dir, "first.txt"), 
    os.path.join(script_dir, "second.text"), 
    os.path.join(script_dir, "third.txt"))
```

What you are doing wrong, is adding `"first.txt"` etc to `script_dir`, and passing that to `os.path.join`. `os.path.join`, however, takes multiple arguments (any number of arguments) and joins them together in the correct way. What your code did, is add those strings together, making: `script_dirfirst.txt`, which would explain why it couldn't find the file.